# Timer stop's firing events winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, garbage-collection

I have time declared like this :

```
private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer();

public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _timer.Interval = 100;
    _timer.Tick += TimerTick;
    _timer.Enabled = true;
}

void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //update some textBoxes some labels etc.
}
```

At some point it just stops ticking why is that ? I saw some post's where the timer was getting garbage collected so to prevent this i used `GC.KeepAlive(_timer);` in one of my methods but even after adding this line it still stops ticking. Am i not preventing the GC in the correct way ? Or something else is happening ? I would like to lower the interval even more but I'm not sure if can go lower than 55ms.

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem with the code you've shown, which leads me to believe the problem and solution lie elsewhere.  Do you ever call `_timer.Stop()` or `_timer.Dispose()`, or set `_timer.Enabled` to `false`?  (Not trying to be patronizing, just listing things that can stop a timer...)

Comment: no i never stop the timer

Comment: `private readonly Timer _timer` keeps the timer alive as long as the form is alive. Are you closing your form and letting that get GCed?

Comment: Well im opening 1 more form but never closing this one it's always open by closing i mean `this.close`

Comment: How do you know it stops ticking ?

Comment: Do you have multiple threads and you somehow enter another thread than where your timer is (such as your new form)? If that is the case, your timer cannot run because you are on different thread.

Comment: Are you blocking the UI thread in some other code? Forms timer runs it's ticks on the UI thread, if the UI thread is blocked the timer can't fire.

Comment: Well i don't have a single line `_timer.Stop()`  `_timer.Enabled=false` im not sure what can block the UI thread

Comment: It could be updating your UI with the same values over-and-over again and leading you to think it stopped.

Comment: No it stops if i put my breakpoint in it wont trigger it. Also it doesn't update some textboxes which obviously require update

Comment: be sure to set the property of _timer.Enabled  =true;